# opening in mobile power bi app specific power bi report hosted on power bi report server

Tags: power-bi-report-server, powerbi-mobile

we have power bi report server with several power bi reports.

we can connect to report server via mobile Power BI app and navigate to specific report manually through the folders.
we can open report (since we have all permissions needed) and it works.

the question is - how to open in Power BI app exact report from outside (from another app) by URL or something?

we do know about ability to specify specific report while connecting Power BI Service hosted reports:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/mobile/mobile-apps-deep-link-specific-location

how to arheive the same functionality with the Power BI Report Server hosted reports?
i.e. how to force openning specific report in mobile app programically?

Answer (score 1):

you can open it by using Office VPN and open that URL , No other option if you are using Power BI Report server

Thanks